# An editable UIwebview in an UIScrollView. Issue with scrolling

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios6, uiscrollview

I have an editable UIWebView into an UIScrollView.

I disabled the scrollview and the bounces on the UIWebView to only rely on the UIScrollView' scrollview.

Each 0.1 second, I have a Timer which detects if the UIWebView content has changed since last check. If so, and if the caret is greater than a given position, the offset fo the scrollView is updated, and the result is pretty good.

My issue is when I go back to edit an already written text.

The UIWebView scrolls on its own view, and the text disappears.

I'd like to use the UIScrollView instead.

Here are two pictures showing the issue:

[image]
[image]

EDIT: Here is a video showing the bug: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9666723/Bug.mov

Thanks for any piece of help.

Comment: Did you find out any solution for this problem @arkan

Comment: Hi @Suhaiyl, No I didn't. :/ I changed my view instead. Good luck and if you find a solution, I would be glad to hear it :-)